# Get the closest node in neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I have 5 Nodes Node1,Node2,Node3,Node4,Node5. i want to get the closest node that connect to Node1 from type of Node5 it can be Node1->Node2->Node5 or Node1->Node3->Node->Node5.
is that possible?

Comment: START n=node(Node1) 
WITH n, abs(n.id - 11111) as val ORDER BY val LIMIT 1
RETURN n

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want to find the shortest path from Node1 to Node5? Is `Node1` a [node label](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/cypherdoc-labels-constraints-and-indexes.html#_labels) that identifies many nodes or a property value that identifies an individual node?

Assuming you have a `name` property that identifies the node:

```
MATCH p=shortestPath( (:Node {name: "Node1"})-[*]->(:Node {name: "Node2"}))
RETURN p
```

If `Node1`, `Node2`, etc are labels:

```
MATCH p=shortestPath((n1:Node1)-[*]->(n5:Node5))
RETURN p
```

Answer (score 1):

`Match p = shortestPath((n1:Node1)-[*]-(n5:Node5)) 
return p`

Refer to this docs for additional tips on the matter:
http://neo4j.com/docs/milestone/query-match.html

On a side note it seems you are using a somewhat deprecated cypher syntax `Start`, that is only recommended to be used with legacy indexes. In newer versions you can use `Match` straight ahead. Refer to the following: http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-start.html